# Dynamically connect DEV and TEST environment in Pentaho concurrently

Tags: datasource, pentaho, jndi

*Current Setup:*

In our current setup we have a single project in two folders - DEV and TEST in the same Pentaho solution repository. Each has its own database. We have passed the Data source connection as a parameter, so we change the database name in kettle.properties. Because of this we are not able work on DEV and TEST environment concurrently.

*Expected:*

I want to run my PENTAHO solution repository against DEV & QA environment on needed basis. Is there a way to connect any one of the connection dynamically without changing anything. Any other external configuration option is available?

Comment: did you get other solutions? I did it like the first answer to this question, in my ktr files, I uses '${source.jndi}'  & '${source.db}'  for db and schema, with this, I can run it via command line at different folder (e.g.   QA folder with QA's kettle.properties, and PRD folder with PRD's kettle.properties), but this cannot work when 'schedule job in remote repository server'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter concept.

Pass the parameter at run time.

For Example

```
call kitchen.bat /file:C:\Pentaho_samples\repository\repository_export.kjb
        "/param:rep_name=PDI2000" "/param:rep_user=admin" "/param:rep_password=password"
        "/param:rep_folder=/public/dev"
        "/param:target_filename=C:\Pentaho_samples\repository\export\dev.xml"
```

similarly specify your database connection details at run time.

Note : You need to change the logic accordingly in your job